# parse error 108 in text file update line

Tags: php

I have this code below for updating a line on a text file.

```
$filename = "flat-file-data.txt"; // File which holds all data
$rowToUpdate = 1; // This is line need to be updated
$newString = "This text is updated\n"; // This is what you want to replace it with

$arrFp = file( $filename ); // Open the data file as an array
// Replace the current element in array which needs to be updated with new string
$arrFp[$rowToUpdate-1] = $newString; 
$numLines = count( $arrFp ); // Count the elements in the array

$fp = fopen( $filename, "w" ); // Open the file for writing
for($i=0; $i&lt;$numLines; $i++) // Overwrite the existing content
{
    fwrite($fp, $arrFp[$i]);
}
fclose( $fp ); // Close the file
```

but unfortunately I get an error saying "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in D:\PROGRAM FILES\wamp\www\mindandsoul\processor.php on line 108". What does suppose it means? how can i get rid of it? any way to fix the error?

Comment: The problem is you have just copied and pasted the code probably from an online tutorial without looking into the pasted code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
for($i=0; $i&lt;$numLines; $i++)
```

the `&lt;` must be replaced with `<`

Like this:

```
for($i=0; $i < $numLines; $i++)
```